# Laraver 5 + Angular 2 + Gulp compile typescript app.js not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, angular

I try to connect laravel and angular2. When I use the command gulp shows that "resources / assets / typescript / app.js <- Not Found". I tried to add an empty file to the directory typescrpit, the compilation is successful but doesn't create app.js in the public/ .

I did everything as it is in this guide: [LINK](https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-and-angular-2-beta-setup/)

```
mix.typescript('app.js','public/',{
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
});
```

[typescrpit()](http://pastebin.com/zNgmrk4y)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the error specifically referring to the `typescript` task? Shouldn't the source file have a `.ts` extension for typescript? Are there other tasks in `gulpfile.js` that might be working on the same file and throwing the error the error (like `mix.version()` for example).

Comment: my gulp file [link](http://pastebin.com/0RuHysFE)

Answer (score 0):

The elixir-typescript version used (^1.1.2) in the tutorial is making all the difference. Just change the version in your package.json to ^1.1.2